# Use XFCE4 Whisker Menu without root privileges

Tags: xfce, non-root-user

We have XFCE 4.10 on our workstations. I don't really like the built-in menu so I'd like to install the Whisker Menu. I don't have any root privileges, though.

I tried building the plugin and installing it with prefix `~/.local`, but the applet is not detected by the XFCE applet manager.

Is there any way to use the Whisker Menu without root privileges?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately xfce4-panel doesn't look for available panel plugins anywhere inside user home directory. And it doesn't have any settings/environment variables to control that either.

So the only natural way left for you is to recompile xfce4-panel yourself and run your modified version.

To make it easy for you I'll give you detailed instructions.

1. Download from http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/ xfce4-panel sources (e.g. xfce4-panel-4.10.0.tar.bz2)
2. Unpack archive and run (and hope that you have all required dependencies):

   ```
   ./configure --prefix="$HOME"/.local \
               --enable-gtk3
   make
   make install
   ```

   Whisker menu doesn't require `--enable-gtk3`, but some other plugins might want it.
3. Make sure that whisker files are in place (if not, you can just copy them) : `~/.local/lib/xfce4/panel/plugins/libwhiskermenu.so` and
   `~/.local/share/xfce4/panel/plugins/whiskermenu.desktop`.
4. Restart xfce4-panel:

   ```
   xfce4-panel --quit
   ~/.local/bin/xfce4-panel
   ```

If xfce4-panel can't find your other plugins, copy them to `~/.local` too.

P.S. I also suggest you to ask your system administrators who have root rights to just install whisker menu on the system instead.